# How to block certain email domain when signing up on my form (php)

Tags: php

Right now all that happens is that it will always say email banned

My code

```
//email validation
    $email = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $domain_name = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
    $domainBlock = 'example.org';
    echo "Domain name is : " . $domain_name;

  if ($domain_name = $domainBlock) {
    $error[] = 'Website Down For Maintenance';
  }
```

Comment: change `$domain_name = $domainBlock` to `$domain_name == $domainBlock`, one sign of `=` is assigning

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `=` sign in the last if statement.

It should be

```
if ($domain_name == $domainBlock) {
    $error[] = 'Website Down For Maintenance';
}
```

Comment: You might want to change that to `==` instead of `-=`

Comment: Oh the irony :D

Comment: Thank you it works, just wondering what is the difference beetween = and ==, I am doing this in study hall and for some reason my school has php.net blocked